# Why triple output in every 230v -> low voltage DC power supply?

Tags: power-supply, output, redundancy

Why do all 12v power supplies produce triple output?
All power supplies that I see at Amazon
  www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=12v%20power%20supply%2030a
or Aliexpress www.aliexpress.com/af/12v-30a-power-supply.html convert 220v AC into **triple 12v**

[image]

Does it mean that these are 3 isolated and independent 120w voltage sources? How do I get single 360w voltage source? The [Commutation cell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutation_cell) principle says that I cannot simply physically wire all 3 output contacts together, right?

Comment: "Why do all 12v power supplies produce triple output?" Uhm, well, they don't?

Comment: Go read the (word deleted) data sheet for the device.

Comment: **Think** for a moment. You want 360 W at 12 V. How much current is that ? How much current do you think one such connector contact can handle ? I'll tell you, less than 30 A. The multiple contacts are there for high current handling. If they were separate supplies you cannot put them in parallel. But they're not, so the  Commutation cell principle does not apply.

Comment: I'm not sure what the commutation cell has to do with it. Open it up and look at the back of the PCB, you'll see they're all on the same track.

Comment: You can connect multiple voltage sources in parallel iff they have the same voltage, but otherwise not.  So the commutation cell principle is not an issue here. // Besides, as other people have mentioned, the outputs are connected = one power supply.  30 Amperes is a lot of current, too much for a single wire to conduct.

Comment: "Having the same voltage" exists only in theory. One phase can be slightly lower than the other and the principle "you can join same voltage lines" is not appropriate anymore. Commutation cell is only appropriate principle foreva.

Comment: The small resistance in the wires is high enough for a small difference in voltage or phase.  The inductance should also help, but I don't think anyone has ever tried connecting two super-conducting generators in parallel wires, so I can't say for sure. // From my understanding of commutation cells, I'd say the principle only applies to boolean or otherwise highly quantified values, eg. positive, zero, negative, high and low voltages and currents, not small differences like 11.9V and 12.1V.

Comment: @OskarSkog But even small difference should imply too much overheat for the powerful sources, shouldn't it?

Comment: That really depends on the difference in voltage and resistance of the wire.   A small enough difference or a high enough resistance will eliminate the issue.   Powerplants are connected the same grid without any issues, everything just needs to be close enough to the correct voltage and close enough to the correct phase.  And if the voltage source can also act as a load (eg. rechargeable batteries, many if not most generators), they will correct each other and the difference in voltage will quickly drop.

Comment: @OskarSkog Here is what [ATX expert saying](http://www.playtool.com/pages/psumultirail/multirails.html#single12): "in case you're ever tempted to hook the independent 12 volt rails together (I've seen people on the Internet who think this is a good idea), don't do it. Your 12v rails may have different ideas about what voltage they should set since they have separate voltage controllers and minimal mismatch draws a lot of current when you connect them together because each tries to force the voltage on the same wires to a different value resulting in PSU shutdown or smoke and sparks."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

30 Amps is a lot of current I must tell you. It is better the manufacturer has provided 3 screw pins per polarity. It actually helps to improve the contact resistance between these screws and the connecting wires, thus reduce the heating and also more area for the heat to dissipate.

Further, think if you have 3 loads of 10 Amps each (say), you can easily connect each screw to its corresponding terminals without unnecessarily trying tie all the three terminations to one screw terminal each!!

They are not isolated by the way, they are all shorted inside within. If you still have doubts, I will suggest using a multi-meter and checking the resistance(Beep-Mode) between them.

Comment: I'm not so sure if the issue is specifically contact resistance, but resistance as a whole.

Comment: Contact resistance is vital since, it is the place of contact where the effective area of cross-section (with some areas in precise contact and some air gaps which do not help in the current flow) and plays a vital role.                                                             Often this contact area is exposed to environment and develops corrosion which further increases the contact resistance. Thus, people use Gold plated contact material often.                     Poor guys like me use Glue gun to cover up that spot !! as a stop gap solution...

Answer (score 7):

The image is self-explanatory:

[image]

Comment: I don't think you need to circle that 30A so much, I didn't notice that you've circled the +V and -V groups. I was almost about to ask why you'd think this would help OP who already knows that 360W/12V=30A, but is asking if it is 3 separate power supplies.

Answer (score 0):

unless otherwise specified, the three output are multi-tap connectors to single source to connect multiple devices, you can use any one of the +V/-V combination to use the full wattage

If the load need to be shared across three connectors a three core cable can be used [image: three core cable]

Comment: I don't think those contacts are rated for 30A - they look more like 10A each. You'll want to distribute the load a bit to prevent them from overheating.

Comment: How would that three core armoured cable be connected?

Comment: @Chu hopefully it _wouldn't be connected_ to 12vdc as that has a very mains look about it. Colour code is old 3-phase, you don't want some joker wiring 380v AC to the other end.

Comment: @John U, exactly, that's why I asked the question. This has been accepted by the OP as the best answer!

Comment: The picture of a three-core cable is silly anyway. If you were really going to do such a thing, you'd use a *six*-core cable, three for each of +V and -V.